# Sending Email after scheduled time when button is pressed

Tags: php, email, cron, task

```
if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))             
{
$to      = 'someone@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test';
$message = 'please approve';
$headers = 'From: noreply@someone.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@someone.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,"-fnoreply@someone.com");

echo 'Email Sent.';
}
```

I use this code to send to send a simple email when a user presses a button so the admin can approve the record entered by the user. Now I want the php code that would allow me to notify the admin if the admin did not approve the record within lets say 7 days. So how can we do that in php? Please do not advise me to use cron jobs websites as I want this to be done in the code just like if button is pressed then wait for 7 days, if not approved within 7 days then send email otherwise not. Cron jobs websites is not useful to me because i am not using their websites to send the form and get it approved or if there is a way that they can help then please advise me. i do not want their other functionalities such as making back up, scan, etc. Only notifying the admin after 7 days if he did not approve the record would be enough.
PS, i use windows, not linux.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have to run a script manually everyday.

Comment: "Cron jobs websites " dont know what this is, but runing a cron job on your site is the right approach.

Comment: i am new to cron jobs, dont know a single thing about it, just saw some websites which provide cron jobs thats why i wrote that. Can you please guide me how i can use cron jobs on my webiste?

Comment: cron jobs is nothing, just write a php script for your requirement and register that script in server with run once every day.

Comment: well i use cpanel and it says you must have a knowledge of linux commands. its asking for that command, not a script...